# Form fields cannot be found until the PDF file is saved again in Acrobat

Tags: c#, itext7

I am using iText 7 (version 8.0.2) to fill in form fields in an existing original PDF (from a third party). Now I have encountered a strange problem. The form fields cannot be found. However, if I only save the PDF file in Adobe Acrobat (without making any changes), all the fields are found. I can see that the file size increases from 74KB to 145KB.

Is there any tool I can use to analyze the structure of the PDF file in a way that allows me to identify what differs between the files?

Can iText 7 be used to trigger a similar automatic extra save of the file? I have tried to do a "normal" dummy open/save to a new file with iText 7. The file can be opened in Acrobat, but the problem persists in that form fields cannot be found with iText 7.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the specific file, which I would have liked to do.

```
public void Test() {
  using var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("in.pdf"), new PdfWriter("out.pdf"));
  var form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, false); // form.GetField("FIELD_NAME") does not work
  var forms = form.GetAllFormFields(); //Empty collection
}
```

Thanks for helping me out here!

Edit:
Using pdftk to dump the fields the result of the initial file (not re-saved in Acrobat), the result are empty. But with the re-saved file all form-data are there.
`pdftk.exe input.pdf dump_data_fields`

Edit:
I have examined the files with iText RUP, this is what I found. First original file, second saved in Adobe Acrobat. NB: I do have some PDF knowledge, but I'm not a professional PDF developer. Maybe I'm looking in wrong direction.

Fields are empty, but the form-field name are found under Pages.
[image]

Fields array now have data (re-saved file).
[image]

Comment: Can you advice on any "simple GUI editor" to examine the file?

Comment: Indeed, there is iText RUPS. There also are a  number of similar tools, e.g. PDFBox PDFDebugger or the "Browse Internal PDF Structure" option of Adobe Acrobat Preflight. But most of all you need to _understand_ what those tools show. Thus, you need to have a fundamental knowledge of the internal PDF structure.

Comment: Thanks, I edited with some iText RUP founding.

Comment: Ok. It's clearly an error in the original PDF that the fields are not in the **AcroForm** entry **Fields**. You should tell the source of the PDF that their form structure is broken and ask them to provide a complete form definition. In particular the file does not require an "extra safe": it is broken and needs a _repair_. You can implement such a repair based on iText: simply visit all document pages, collect the widget annotations from their **Annots** arrays, determine the root fields of those annotations by following the **Parent** entries, dropping duplicates, and setting the **Fields**.

Comment: Thanks for the input and sorting this out. I have been struggling with this in my mind for a while. The Producer metadata reads:  
`Acrobat Distiller 15.0 (Windows); modified using iTextSharp™ 5.5.3 ©2000-2014 iText Group NV (AGPL-version)`
Can it be an old way of producing the PDF or is it just faulty?

Comment: I did a workaround shown in my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77528161/2383045).  
But when I tested this, I noticed that when I open the original file (or even the one that is fixed) in Adobe Acrobat, the file is flagged as modified in the program. This causes the application to prompt to save the changes even if no adjustments were made in Acrobat. Perhaps the most pragmatic solution is to open the original file in Acrobat and save it (repair it). However, I would have preferred to handle this automatically with iText.

Comment: Well, without inspecting the file in question I could only guess what causes the prompt to save the changes. But if it is broken in one way, it may also be broken in other ways. Concerning the producer metadata - I doubt that Acrobat Distiller or iText 5.5.3 created the broken form structure. Most likely there were also other PDF processors manipulating the file but not adding to the producer line.

Comment: Perhaps it's not worthwhile to invest effort in resolving the underlying issue if it's inherently broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to to mkl's comment, I did a method to "repair" the broken PDF based on the KB from iText (https://kb.itextsupport.com/home/it7kb/faq/why-are-the-acrofields-in-my-document-empty):

```
private static void FixMissingAcroFields(PdfDocument pdf) {
    var root = pdf.GetCatalog();
    var form = root.GetPdfObject().GetAsDictionary(PdfName.AcroForm);
    var fields = form.GetAsArray(PdfName.Fields);

    for (var i = 1; i <= pdf.GetNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        var page = pdf.GetPage(i);
        var annotations = page.GetAnnotations();
        foreach (var annotation in annotations) {
            fields.Add(annotation.GetPdfObject());
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call it when FormFilds is empty.

```
var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFile), new PdfWriter(targetFile));
var form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, false);

if (!form.GetAllFormFields().Any()) {
    FixMissingAcroFields(pdf);
    form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, false);
}
...
```

I'll also try to report the broken PDF to the source/creator.